# Ordenação de listas retorna "None"

Tags: python, lista

Estou a fazer um programa que renderiza chaves para o euro milhões, mas as chaves dão `None`, qual é o meu erro?

```
import random
print('Chave do Euromilhões')

num= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50]
estr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]


while  True:
    n1= random.randint(1,50)
    if n1 in num:
        #print(n1, end=', ')
        break
while  True:
    n2= random.randint(1,50)
    if n2 in num and n1!=n2:
        #print(n2, end=', ')
        break
while  True:
    n3= random.randint(1,50)
    if n3 in num and n1!=n3 and n2!=n3:
        #print(n3, end=', ')
        break
while  True:
    n4= random.randint(1,50)
    if n4 in num and n1!=n4 and n2!=n4 and n3!=n4:
        #print(n4, end=', ')
        break
while  True:
    n5= random.randint(1,50)
    if n5 in num and n1!=n4 and n2!=n5 and n3!=n5 and n4!=n5:
        #print(n5, end='. ')
        break

Números= [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5]

Números=Números.sort(reverse= False)

print(Números)


while  True:
    e1= random.randint(1,11)
    if e1 in num:
        #print(e1, end=', ')
        break
while  True:
    e2= random.randint(1,11)
    if e2 in num and e1!=e2:
        #print(e2, end='. ')
        break

Estrelas= [e1,e2]
Estrelas=Estrelas.sort(reverse= False)


print('Os números do euromilhões são:',Números)
print('As estrelas são:', Estrelas)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) ordena a lista *in-place* (ou seja, modifica a própria lista, em vez de retornar outra). E seu retorno é `None`, por isso não faz sentido atribuir seu resultado em uma variável.

Então em vez de:

```
Números = Números.sort(reverse=False)
```

Faça apenas:

```
Números.sort(reverse=False)
```

O mesmo vale para:

```
Estrelas.sort(reverse=False)
```

---

Ou se preferir, crie as listas já ordenadas, usando [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
Números = sorted([n1,n2,n3,n4,n5], reverse=False)

Estrelas = sorted([e1,e2], reverse=False)
```

Se bem que o valor *default* de `reverse` já é `False`, então poderia ser simplesmente:

```
Números.sort()
Estrelas.sort()

# ou
Números = sorted([n1,n2,n3,n4,n5])
Estrelas = sorted([e1,e2])
```

---

Não diretamente relacionado, mas você pode simplificar esse monte de `while` assim:

```
import random
print('Chave do Euromilhões')

numeros_possiveis = range(1, 51)
estrelas_possiveis = range(1, 12)

Números = sorted(random.sample(numeros_possiveis, 5))
Estrelas = sorted(random.sample(estrelas_possiveis, 2))

print('Os números do euromilhões são:',Números)
print('As estrelas são:', Estrelas)
```

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) cria uma sequência de números (lembrando que o valor final não é incluso, por isso coloquei 51 e 12) e [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) escolhe uma determinada quantidade de números da sequência indicada (e já garante que eles não serão repetidos).

Comment: Eu tinha feito isso inicialmente, mas não me estava a dar certo, mas obrigada na mesma, já funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

O método [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) apenas ordena a lista [*in-place*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) e retorna sempre `None`.

Uma alternativa seria usar a função [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), que retorna uma cópia ordenada da lista e faz exatamente o que você quer, por exemplo:

```
Numeros = sorted(Numeros)
Estrelas = sorted(Estrelas)
```

Para gerar uma lista de inteiros de forma sequêncial, voce poderia usar a função geradora [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range), veja só:

```
num = list(range(1, 10 + 1))
print(num)
```

Saída:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Ao invés de você usar a *força bruta* para sortear uma quantidade *n* de elementos de uma lista sem que eles se repitam, você pode usar o método [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), algo assim:

```
import random

x = random.sample([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], k=5)
print(x)
```

Possível Saída:

```
[9, 6, 7, 3, 8]
```

Considerando tudo que foi dito, seu programa poderia ser reescrito da seguinte forma:

```
from random import sample

Numeros = sorted(sample(range(1, 50 + 1), 5))
Estrelas = sorted(sample(range(1, 11 + 1), 2))

print('Os numeros do euromilhoes sao: ', Numeros)
print('As estrelas sao: ', Estrelas)
```

Possível Saída:

```
Os numeros do euromilhoes sao:  [1, 13, 16, 41, 45]
As estrelas sao:  [1, 6]
```